# How Old is Mako?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra, age

I have heard that Bolin, from *The Last Airbender: Legend of Korra*, is 18-years-old, or thereabouts. From Bryke we have heard that Mako is older than Bolin. How much older is Mako than Bolin?

Answer (score 2):

Mako raised Bolin. In order to truly do that the way he did, Mako must at least be 3-5 years older than him. If Korra is 17, Bolin could be 16 1/2, and because she is older, that could explain why he liked her so. If Bolin is 16, we could say Mako is 19. There is still a heathy age difference between Korra and Bolin, and their ages are all relatively the same.

Answer (score 2):

Mako is 2 years older than Bolin (since he was 8 when his mom and dad died and Bolin was 6) but now, Mako is 19 (Book 3), Korra is 17/18 (B3) and Bolin is 18 (B3).

Answer (score 1):

Umm I would guess about 17 or 18. I wouldn't say 19 because I know age is but number but in most cartoons they usually have their boyfriends or girlfriends the same age and since Korra is 17, I'm guessing around 17.

Comment: I really don't think Bolin is 18 years old, because in the creator cuts they said that they are all about the same age.. and Korra is 17 so doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 1):

Since Mako was 8 when his parents died and Bolin was 6 Mako is 2 years older than Bolin, therefore, since Mako is currently 19 Bolin is probably 17 or 16 1/2. That is an appropriate age for Bolin cause he dated Korra who is 17 years old. and sort of appropriate for Mako.

[image]

Comment: I agree with this a 100%!!

Answer (score 0):

I remember when the series first aired on TV I went on nick.com and they had a sheet for each character and it had info on each character of the show. Things like what element they bent, or what they liked; basic info. One of the things that were listed was each character's age. Mako was 18, Korra was 17 and Bolin was 16. Now I tried finding the sheet again but they seemed to have taken it off the site. So the least I can say that those are their ages for book one, between books 2-4 I wouldn't know how to tell you.

Answer (score -1):

Only info showing up on sites is that his age is unknown.

References:

- http://avataraang.tumblr.com
- http://avatar.answers.wikia.com

Comment: I just said that?

Answer (score -2):

Mako is either 19 or 20. Most likely he's 19 because they don't want to make him too much older than his love interest.

Answer (score -2):

Mako raised Bolin. In order to truly do that the way he did, Mako must at least be 3-5 years older than him. If Korra is 17, Bolin could be 16 1/2, and because she is older, that could explain why he liked her so. If Bolin is 16, we could say Mako is 19. There is still a heathy age difference between Korra and Bolin, and their ages are all relatively the same.

Comment: What happened here?  It looks like this answer, which was unrelated and posted in August, was edited by "the Community" to be an exact copy of Rai's answer about 12 minutes after he posted it in September...